# Need to capture ID after clicking on submit button

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I am using selenium with java and In my application , whenever I click on submit button, system generates random ID, I need to capture that ID displayed on screen(a div) and then put in other field to ensure, all fields are filled and we are able to edit as well.

Comment: please paste the code that you have tried and what exception that you are getting, then any one of us will hep you

Comment: And also paste html code for the webelement

Answer (score 0):

The simpelst way is this:

1. Create a variable that will contain the id:

   String myID;
2. After id is created you need to capture the text in the filed:

   myID = driver.findElement(By.id(".....")).getText();

After this, the ID will be saved in myID.

3. to see if it worked, run the following line:

System.out.println(myID);

If the output in the console is the same as in a generated ID field then all worked correctly.